# Having column with decimal type with 2 precision. But while save data in it, It saves value with only one precision.

Tags: postgresql, decimal, ruby-2.2

I am using Ruby 2.2.4 and PostgreSQL.
I have created migration:

```
add_column :plans, :price, :decimal, precision: 7, scale: 2
```

When I am going to create new record, it will save value in *price* column with only one precision.

Why it happens?
I want value with 2 precisions.

Ex: 
Current value which is save: `20.0`
I want: `20.00`

Comment: it shows you 20.0 it does not save it any special way. or it can show you 20.00, but again it does not matter it save it in special way. float value of 20.0 and 20.00 is same. so look at displaying differently, not saving. btw I'm talking for Postgres only

Answer (score 0):

```
select round(20.0 , 2), 20.00::double precision, 20.00::numeric
```

[image]

so you can use `round()` for fixed number of digits after the dot

Answer (score 0):

I have used number_to_currency(@price). It is a method of ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper